# Construct a column with lagged values

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following script that creates a data table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(6,7,8,9,10), c = c(22,0,0,0,0))
```

I want to replace the values of `c` in rows 2 to 5 as follows

```
   a  b  c
1: 1  6 22
2: 2  7 31
3: 3  8 42
4: 4  9 55
5: 5 10 70
```

which is something like

```
c = a + b + shift(c, n = 1, fill = 0, type="lag")
```

In other words, keep row 1 the same and apply the formula to rows 2 to 5.

I have tried

```
dt[2:nrow(dt), c := a + b + shift(c, n = 1, fill = 0, type="lag")]
```

but that gives

```
   a  b  c
1: 1  6 22
2: 2  7  9
3: 3  8 11
4: 4  9 13
5: 5 10 15
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is data.tablish, but a variation on your attempt works: `dt[-1L, c := cumsum(a+b)+dt$c[1L]]`

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` way to do it, considering the fact that add `a + b + c[i-1]` is actually doing a cumulative sum of `a + b`:

```
dt[, c := shift(cumsum(shift(a+b, n = 1, type = "lead")) + c[1], 
                n = 1, type = "lag", fill = c[1])]
dt
   a  b  c
1: 1  6 22
2: 2  7 31
3: 3  8 42
4: 4  9 55
5: 5 10 70
```

Answer (score 4):

We could also do (a variation of @Frank's suggestion)

```
dt[, c:= c[1L]][-1L, c := cumsum(a+b)+c]
dt
#   a  b  c
#1: 1  6 22
#2: 2  7 31
#3: 3  8 42
#4: 4  9 55
#5: 5 10 70
```

Comment: Yeah, this is an elegant way to go about it.

Comment: Frank's suggestion worked for what I needed. The fact that I was doing cumulative summing in the example was an inadvertent consequence of how I constructed the example. I'm still not clear on why it works. I get that the code inside the first [] replaces all the c entries with the first. But what does the -1L in the second [] do? A pointer to an explanation of the use of L in this situation would be great!

Comment: @JerryN  Here, we are specifying the 'i' i.e row index.  `-1` implies selecting all rows except the first one.  I used `L` to give an integer representation (which could be fast in some cases).